# ASP.NET MVC - Passar dados entre Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tenho duas tabelas: **Tb_1** e **Tb_2**; ambas possuem uma coluna ***id*** e estão relacionadas entre si num banco de dados Microsoft SQL.

Por exemplo: Selecionei o registro *nº 2* na **Tb_1**. Ao acionar o comando *Criar*, a **Tb_2** recebe o *nº 2* no seu campo ***id***

Como faço para quando eu clicar no botão *Criar* na **Tb_1**, envie a mesma ***id*** selecionada na **Tb_1** para a **Tb_2** ?

Comment: Coloque essas duas classes na sua pergunta !!!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, se alguém quiser uma dica:

Estava assim:

```
// GET: tb_visitas/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.id_broc = new SelectList(db.tb_brochuras, "id_broc", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_g = new SelectList(db.tb_despertai, "id_g", "tema");
    ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.tb_estrangeiros, "id", "nome");
    ViewBag.id_fol = new SelectList(db.tb_folhetos, "id_fol", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_livros = new SelectList(db.tb_livros, "id_livros", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_wp = new SelectList(db.tb_sentinela, "id_wp", "tema");
    return View();
}
```

Daí alterei para isso:

```
// GET: tb_visitas/Create
public ActionResult Create(tb_estrangeiros estrangeiros)
{
    ViewBag.id_broc = new SelectList(db.tb_brochuras, "id_broc", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_g = new SelectList(db.tb_despertai, "id_g", "tema");
    ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.tb_estrangeiros, "id", "nome", estrangeiros.id);
    ViewBag.id_fol = new SelectList(db.tb_folhetos, "id_fol", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_livros = new SelectList(db.tb_livros, "id_livros", "descricao");
    ViewBag.id_wp = new SelectList(db.tb_sentinela, "id_wp", "tema");
    return View();
}
```